# Is there a hotkey to remove a bookmark?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, hotkeys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> [hotkey](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) bookmarks the current page, but can't be used to remove the bookmark. Without using mouse, the only way I know to delete a bookmark is pressing <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> six times + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after using this hotkey.
Bookmarks sidebar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) doesn't highlight the currently active tab.

I frequently save articles to my "read later" folder and removing them after reading is  a slight hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to open the pop-up and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (R is underlined in "Remove Bookmark" when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> six times, it moves tab focus backwards.